# SQL Server - How to manage hierarchical data in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I use SQL Server 2000.

Suppose I have two tables like the following:

```
Area
----------------------------------
ID| Name   | HierarchyLevel
----------------------------------
1 | World  |     1
2 | America|     2
3 | Europe |     2
4 | Africa |     2
5 | USA    |     3
```

and

```
AreaHierarchy
------------------------
ID | ParentID | ChildID
------------------------
 1 |   1      |    2
 2 |   1      |    3
 3 |   1      |    4
 4 |   2      |    5
```

where

AreaHierarchy.ParentID and AreaHierarchy.ChildID are FKs of Area.ID

How can I find the nth parent of USA?

Is it possible without looping?

Probably not.

Comment: This will become horribly inefficient for a structure of any significant depth. Look into HierarchyID or if you are using older than SQL 2008, look into the Adjacency List Model.

Comment: For 'any version' what do you mean.  I've not used anything older than SQL Server 2000, but older versions don't even have Stored Procedures, User Defined Functions.  What is the oldest version you need to support?  Either way, you're going to need a loop or recursion.

Comment: @Dems, sql server 2000, 2005, 2008.

Comment: Assuming no change to your data structure, and as you need to support sql server 2000: you need to use recursive function calls, a loop, or dynamic sql building up n joins for your query.

Comment: If you can change your data structure to precalculate a 'parents' field as per Robert's answer, that works.  But I tend to avoid such options to avoid creating legacy baggage which makes maintenance harder.  I do use such options when performance would otherwise be insufficient (poor performance = no product = no maintenance, so take the hit where necessary, but only where necessary, imho)

Comment: -1: The SQL Server version will greatly affect the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No loops, no recursion

The best thing is to add additional field in your second table, that would be called ie. `Parents` and would simply store parent IDs in a string like:

```
AreaHierarchy
------------------------------------
ID | ParentID | ChildID | Parents
------------------------------------
 1 |    1     |    2    | 1/
 2 |    1     |    3    | 1/
 3 |    1     |    4    | 1/
 4 |    2     |    5    | 1/2/
```

This way you can easily get to any parent in the branch without recursion or any other complicated procedure. The cost in processing is very small you just copy parent's `Parents` value and add one more ID. And since you probably need to read more than write/update, this is the best solution to your problem.

And if I were you, I'd just keep one table for the data you have. Join both tables into one. Level could also be computed based on counting slashes in `Parents` varchar value but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

### Additional 'catch' you should be aware of

If your data is mostly reads/writes and much less updates, this structure is really performant. But if your table does a lot more updates than read/writes, you should avoid this technique. Why? Imagine you have a very deep tree with lots of children. Changing a parent of some node high up in near the root would mean you should update `Parents` of the whole subtree nodes.

Comment: Why use only one table? Querying becomes hard in that way.

Comment: For large hierarchies, creating and maintain this "parents" field can become very inefficient.  But for relatively static structures, this 'precalculation' is quite quick.  Where the string becomes long, parsing it can get realtively slow, maybe even slower than a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Dems, this technique should work well in conjunction with App programming languages like C#.

Comment: For large hierarchies this "parents" feature can become really deep recursive call as well, doesn't it? As I said it depends on what his data is about to accomplish.

Comment: That's true, you could parse the string in the applicaiton.  But then you tightly bind the database implementation to the application, which is bad practice in my world.  It's all about scale and maintainability though.

Comment: Why in the world would one table make queries harder? His structure assumes one parent per node, so it is in no way more complicated.

Comment: I agree, having a second table to hold this data is more normalised but superfluous (in my opinion) and certainly doesn't make anything any harder...

Comment: that's what I meant.  2 tables = superfluous.  1 table != harder. :)

Comment: @Dems, for this moment this technique works well for me. So I am accepting this.

Comment: If you're going to maintain this field (probably using a trigger?) then consider going the whole hog. Create a second table which has the fields [child_id,parent_id,depth] and precalculate every tree traversal. That would slow any alterations to the tree, use more disk space, but also give the fastest route to answering the nth_parent question.

Comment: @JMSA: also be aware of the additional 'catch' I've put in my answer.

Comment: The use of a trailing separator makes this much easier to work with. Calculating the parentage of a child is just a straight concatenation without having to do any checking for empty parentage. As with a lineage that includes the record's own ID, depth is still just a matter of counting the separators.

Comment: To create the parentage from scratch, create an update-join that sets the parentage of every record based on that of its parent. Run this at least as many times as the maximum depth and the parentage will be fully regenerated- this works even if the parentage is completely corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Should work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE find_nth_parent 
    @id INT,
    @level INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @counter INT
    SET @counter = 1

    DECLARE @currentItem INT
    DECLARE @currentItemNew INT

    SET @currentItem = @id

    WHILE @counter <= @level
    BEGIN
        SET @currentItemNew = NULL
        SELECT @currentItemNew = ParentID FROM AreaHierarchy WHERE ChildId = @currentItem
        IF @currentItemNew IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT NULL
            RETURN 
        END
        SET @currentItem = @currentItemNew
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    END
    SELECT @currentItem
END
```

Calling

```
EXEC find_nth_parent 5,2
```

returns 1 which means "World" (2nd parent), calling

```
EXEC find_nth_parent 5,1
```

return 2, which means "America" (1st parent).

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it possible without Looping?

Comment: it's possible without looping...in that you can create a SQL string with as many levels of joins as you need and then execute that dynamically...pain though

Comment: The is no single query that could do this for "n depth" without using Common Table Experssions. That still has to do recurssion, whcih is essnetially a novel kind of loop. But it avoids T-SQL loops, at which TSQL itself isn't actually that efficient. In CTEs the loop is inside the database engine, which is much much faster...

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion.  If you have SQL Server 2005 or newer you can use Common Table Expressions.  If not you realistically need to use User Defined Functions.

An example of a UDF to do that could be...

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_nth_parent(area_id AS INT, n as INT)
RETURNS INT
AS

IF (n = 0) RETURN area_id

DECLARE @return INT
SELECT
   @return = dbo.get_nth_parent(AreaHierarchy.ParentID, n-1)
FROM
   AreaHierarchy
WHERE
   ChildID = area_id

RETURN @return
```

An example using Common Table Experessions could be...

```
DECLARE @hierarchy TABLE (
   parent_id  INT,
   child_id   INT
)
INSERT INTO @hierarchy SELECT 1,2
INSERT INTO @hierarchy SELECT 1,3
INSERT INTO @hierarchy SELECT 1,4
INSERT INTO @hierarchy SELECT 2,5


;WITH
   relative_distance (
      child_id,
      parent_id,
      distance
   )
AS
(
   SELECT
      child_id,
      parent_id,
      1
   FROM
      @hierarchy

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      [relative_distance].child_id,
      [hierarchy].parent_id,
      [relative_distance].distance + 1
   FROM
      [relative_distance]
   INNER JOIN
      @hierarchy AS [hierarchy]
         ON [hierarchy].child_id = [relative_distance].parent_id
)

SELECT
   parent_id
FROM
   [relative_distance]
WHERE
   child_id = 5
   AND distance = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2005+, you'd use a CTE in a function:

```
create function get_parent(@child as int, @parent_level as int)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @parent int

    ;with parentage as (
         select 
             h.parent_id, 
             h.child_id,
             0 as level
         from 
             areahierarchy h
         where
             h.child_id = @child
         union all
         select
             h.parent_id,
             h.child_id,
             p.level + 1 as level
         from
             areahierarchy h
             inner join parentage p on
                 h.parent_id = p.child_id
         where
             p.level < @parent_level
    )

    select @parent = p.child_id from parentage p 
    where level = (select max(level) from parentage)

    return @parent
end
```

Comment: oh come on, use a better CTE name than "p" and I'll guive you +1!  That's just sloppy and lazy :)

Comment: and while doing it you can omit the semicolon, can't you?

Comment: No, CTE's need the preceding TSQL statement to terminate with a semi colon (afaik).  I guess it's legacy due to other uses of the WITH key word.  I'm convinced they could have found a better keyword, but I wasn't there to see why they chose WITH :)

Comment: don't really know. I've never used semicolons in the past and CTEs worked as well. But I don't know whether there were any sentences before them. Maybe they started my SPs. Yours starts with a declaration.

Comment: Changed to be `parentage`. Also, you can omit the `;`, but it's just a force of habit.

Comment: @Dems: WITH is the ANSI standard keyword. I think it originated in DB2, but don't quote me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want support back to SQL Server 2000, but I think it should be noted that the SQL Server 2008 Hierarchy ID function GetAncestor() does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested set model by Joe Celko https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

or even better The closure Table model